# MSAL and AndroidX are not compatible?

Tags: azure, active-directory, authorization, azure-ad-msal, androidx

I am unable to use Azure Active Directory B2C authentication(Microsoft Authentication library, MSAL ) in my Android project with AndroidX dependencies. The chrome browser shows a blank page when I click on "Facebook sign in" and I also noticed a few log errors in the Android studio log cat reported from the MSAL lib. The same project works fine without AndroidX dependencies. Can someone suggest a workaround or a possible fix to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue but it has not yet been prioritized for a fix. The product team is aware and is updating the thread below.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/354

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully integrated Azure B2C authorization into my latest android app  with "com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.2.+" and Androidx components as dependencies.
There are still a few issues that need to be resolved. But these are not showstoppers for now. 
* Login with Facebook always returns error
* Browser Activity always remains open and remains in the app back stack.